# Cannot change chmod from bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I made a script to copy an image to a temporary directory, convert it to an another format, then move it to a final directory.
But i can't get the chmod command to work, the file is copied to the temporary directory but it's chmod is stuck on -rw------- (the original chmod of the file).

If i apply a 777 chmod on the original file, the copied one get a -rwx------ instead of a -rwxrwxrwx

The copied and orignal files have the same user.

```
TS=$(date +"%Y")/$(date +"%m")/$(date +"%d")/$(date +"%Hh%Ms%S")
PATHTMP="/tmp/faxtiff"

mkdir -p $PATHTMP
chmod 777 $PATHTMP
cp $FILE $PATHTMP
chmod 777 $PATHTMP/$FILE
convert $PATHTMP/$FILE -scale '50%x100%!' $PATHTMP/fax.jpg
chmod 777 $PATHTMP/fax.jpg
mkdir -p /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
chmod 777 /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
#rm $PATHTMP/$FILE
mv $PATHTMP/*.jpg /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mdpc is correct. I don't know why somebody downvoted your question, but...

If root owns the file, you should be able (assuming you have access of course) to do a `sudo chmod...`, and that should work.

If, however, you don't want root to own the file anymore, you'll need to do a `sudo chown $USER <filename>` to cause the file to be owned by the user you are logged in as.

I haven't tried your script, but go ahead and try the following, noting 2 things:

1) Don't go around chowning things that you shouldn't. I don't know the context of this question, and it may be bad, very bad, or extremely extremely bad to chown the files in question (read: abuse of power). However, if you are creating this content and are implicitly (or explicitly) being given permission to mod these files, then it shouldn't be a problem.

2) I commented out a couple chowns that you shouldn't need. Remember, you can always do a `ls -l` to see the ownership of a given file.

```
TS=$(date +"%Y")/$(date +"%m")/$(date +"%d")/$(date +"%Hh%Ms%S")
PATHTMP="/tmp/faxtiff"

mkdir -p $PATHTMP
#sudo chown -R $USER $PATHTMP 
chmod 777 $PATHTMP
cp $FILE $PATHTMP
sudo chown $PATHTMP/$FILE
chmod 777 $PATHTMP/$FILE
convert $PATHTMP/$FILE -scale '50%x100%!' $PATHTMP/fax.jpg
#shouldn't need to chown here if the script is being run as the logged in user.
chmod 777 $PATHTMP/fax.jpg
mkdir -p /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
#chown $USER /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
chmod 777 /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
#rm $PATHTMP/$FILE
mv $PATHTMP/*.jpg /home/argent/faxes-recus/$TS
```

Comment: Thank you, i applied your methods and i made my script work as i wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT the owner of the file in question, you cannot do a `chmod` operation on the file.